# Trying to blend a submarine partially submerged in water

Tags: opengl, graphics, jogl

So i am doing an JOGL project in which i am drawing a submarine that can rise/sink and move around a map, - note this map is just a massive quad_strip.

anyway, i have the following code for doing the blending.

```
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    gl.glColor4f(0.949f, 0.816f, 0.588f, 1f);
    gridFloor.display(drawable);

    submarine.setHeight(subHeight);
    submarine.display(drawable);

    gl.glColor4f(0.298f, 0.7333f, 0.909f, 0.04f);
    gridSea.display(drawable);

    gl.glFlush();
```

NOTE: the gridfloor, submarine, and gridsquare objects are all GLEventListners.

So this is all fine and dandy. When it prints, i have positioned the submarine to display at y=2 and the sea level at y=1.5. So the submarine at this point should be above the water line. But this is what i get instead.[image]

As you can probably tell, i am very new to JOGL and any help would be massively appreciated.

EDIT: this is what i am trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you disable the depth test, anything you draw to the screen will get drawn on top of what is already there.  That is why the water is being drawn on top of the submarine.

```
gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Solution: don't disable the depth test.

Comment: Quote from the teacher - "Make the sea
surface semitransparent by enabling blending and disabling depth test." -_- thankyou so much, worked a treat

Comment: @RyanTurnbull: Could it be that your teacher doesn't understand blending, was struggling with it at some point and figured additive plending with depth test enabled would not look totally wrong? Anyway, correct way to render transparent stuff is by having *depth test __enabled__* and *sorting* blended geometry *far to near*.